# Diseño en Android no se aplica al ejecutar en un dispositivo físico

Tags: android, xml

Buen día, nunca había tenido problemas de este tipo con el diseño pero estoy tratando de usar el material de Google que tiene ya por defecto en sus ultimas versiones:

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

Quiero crear un botón redondeado y un botón sin backgroud solo con las líneas de color (Outlined)
cuando aplico el diseño en Android si se mira correctamente pero al ejecutarlo en el teléfono no aplica el cambio.

he tratado de aplicarlo con otra librería:

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'

Pero tampoco funciona, Este es mu archivo `themes.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="Theme.Pedidos_lab" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

y este es mi `styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar" />

<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>

</style>

<!-- set the rounded drawable as background to your bottom sheet -->
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_shape</item>
</style>
```

Finalmente tengo mi archivo xml donde quiero aplicar dicho diseño:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnParaMi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:text="@string/btnParaMi"
    app:backgroundTint="#7D9E34"
    app:cornerRadius="15dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnParaOtraPersona"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:text="@string/btnParaOtra"
    android:textColor="#7D9E34"
    app:cornerRadius="15dp"
    app:strokeColor="#7D9E34" />
```

Donde los atributos que no son reconocidos son:

```
app:cornerRadius="15dp"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
```

Tambien he usado este:

```
style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logologin"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_secutiry_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logologin"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
    tools:targetApi="n">
```

A pesar de que en el diseño si se ve correctamente pero en el dispositivo NO, he estado modificando muchas cosas en estos archivos pero nada parece funcionar, que podría ser el problema y que mas podría hacer para solventarlo, espero que alguien me pueda instruir de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿en la vista de "run" se te muestra algún tipo de error al lanzar la app?

Comment: Hola @FranCámara la verdad no, ni uno solo, aunque no creo que se trate de algún tipo de error porque solo es diseño nada de código

Comment: Entonces ese el problema, al lanzar la app, si no has implementado nada de código en la actividad principal, la app no hace nada, ni quiera te carga la vista que has implementado.

Comment: @FranCámara aunque no soy un experto en Android juraría que el diseño plano de una aplicación no tiene nada que ver con la programación a menos que se le quieran realizar funciones, por lo tanto no le encuentro sentido el porque el problema debería estar en el código, solo estoy implementando un diseño.

Comment: No es que yo sea un experto pero, como mínimo, se que en una actividad o fragmento, para poder visualizar una pantalla se tiene que implementar el onCreate() o el onCreateView() respectivamente, para recuperar los elementos de la vista una vez usas en inflate(). Estoy convencido de que te falta eso.

Comment: Pon el `manifest`

Comment: Ya he agregado el Manifest  @FranqoBalsamo